# Using Facebook Graph API To Get Comments from a Facebook Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have used Facebook Comments plugins in my website. Now I want to fetch all comments in a page. I have followed [this article](http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2015/06/use-api-to-get-fb-comments-plugin-posts.html). But i am getting the following error.

**GET Request** to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=https://www.example.com/page&access_token=my_fb_access_token
```

**Response Error**

**Message =>** (#100) Tried accessing none existing field(comments) on type (URL)

**Code =>** 100

Comment: i don´t think it is possible to get the comments of an url with the api, at least not anymore.

Comment: There are some android apps i think they have done this in there apps. Like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.insomnia.kenya.newsi) one app.